# Nginx received DDOS attack

Tags: nginx, ddos

My website received DDOS attacks (confirmed).
I use Nginx as the reverse proxy server and have 3 WebApps (A,B,C) in the backend. The status is very strange. In DDOS status:

1. Nginx cannot return backend (A and C) results and show 504, but can return backend B.
2. Access A and C directly (without through Nginx), Okay (performance is normal).

I thought the connections were exhausted, but as #1 mentioned, the B content can be returned.

BTW: netstat -nat|grep ESTABLISHED|wc -l show more than 10,000.

Any ideas or suggestions?